# Laravel 5.4 | How to upload image using bootstrap fileinput?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-io, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use bootstrap-fileinput plugin to upload a profile image in a laravel project
 here is the view

```
@section('content')

<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
     <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"> </div>
                    <div>
                         <span class="btn default btn-file">
                               <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
                                     <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
                                           <input type="file" name="..."> </span>
                                                   <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
                    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

The objective is to upload this image to storage dir and store the path to file in db table, but I have no clue how to do that, I am submitting the form via POST to a store method in my controller.
Here is that function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
     $this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'dob' => 'required',
    'mobile_no' => 'unique:customers',
    'adhar_no' => 'unique:customers',

     ]);

    $customer = new customer;

    $customer->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $customer->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $customer->gender = $request->gender;
    $customer->dob = $request->dob;
    $customer->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
    $customer->adhar_no = $request->adhar_no;
    $customer->street = $request->street;


    $customer->save();
    return redirect('home/customer');

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With laravel 5.4 it's really easy to get the file from the request. In your case you can use :

```
$file = $request->file('file');
```

Or:

```
$file = $request->file;
```

To store the file you can use the `store` method as follow:

```
$path = $request->file->store('the/path');
```

After that, you can store the returned path ($path) in your database with the other customer details.

For more details please visit this page: [Retrieving Uploaded Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) and if you want to validate the file before processing it please see this: [Validation Image Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-image)

I hope this will help you. Best of luck.